# Creating new column in R based on different column with a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, mean

I try to create a new column in R, which contains the mean of values of a different column but for their respective date.

My data frame looks something like this:

```
Temp  Date
4    2018-01-01
3    2018-01-01
2    2018-01-02
2    2018-01-02
```

I now want to create a third column, with the mean temperature for each day. So that it looks like this:

```
Temp  Date       mean_Temp
4    2018-01-01   3.5
3    2018-01-01   3.5
2    2018-01-02    2
2    2018-01-02    2
```

I already tried:

```
 for (i in as.list(df$Date)) {
   df$mean_Temp[i] <- paste(mean(df$Temp))
}
```

But that doesn't work, it only returns the overall mean of the temperature and doesn't calculate the mean for every day individually.
Thank you guys, I hope I made my problem clear.

Comment: Why a for loop? Why not `df$mean_Temp <- ave(df$Temp, df$Date, mean)`?

Comment: That doesn't work, I get an error that says: Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors... Maybe because Date is in date format?

Comment: And why `paste()`?  or, in tidyverse, `df %>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate(mean_Temp=mean(Temp, na.rm=TRUE), .groups="drop")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use a for loop in this case, since it is utterly unnecessary.

Here is a `tidyverse` approach. Based on your desired output, each `Date` would still have two records after the mean is calculated. If you only want a single row for each `Date`, use `summarise()` instead of `mutate()`.

### mutate()

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate(mean_Temp = mean(Temp))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Date [2]
   Temp Date       mean_Temp
  <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
1     4 2018-01-01       3.5
2     3 2018-01-01       3.5
3     2 2018-01-02       2  
4     2 2018-01-02       2
```

### summarise()

```
df %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarize(mean_Temp = mean(Temp))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Date       mean_Temp
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 2018-01-01       3.5
2 2018-01-02       2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Date) %>% mutate(mean_Temp = mean(Temp))
```

When grouping with dplyr, you can either use `summarise` or `mutate`. `summarise` will return one row per group while `mutate` will add/modify one column and repeat the value for all the entries in each group.